# Laravel 5.5 Redis + Socket.IO wont work

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I've been at this for hours and I can't figure this out. So I'm using **Laravel 5.5** and my **PHP version is 7**. Now my project is finished but I'm wanting to add Real-time communication between the users. I tried to test some things out but it just won't work. My local development environment is on a MAC, and I'm using Laravel Valet to serve my website.

I followed this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51?page=1)

First I installed Redis & Socket.io as followed

```
$ composer require predis/predis
$ npm install express ioredis socket.io --save
```

Then I installed redis server using brew and then started it

```
redis-server --port 3001
```

Now I made my event (App\Events\NewUserSignup) as followed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewUserSignup implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $username;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username)
    {
        //
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        \Log::info('Event fired');
        return new Channel('test-channel');
    }
}
```

Then I created my Socket.js (Root) file in the root directory as followed:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Then I two new routes like this inside of my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/broadcasting/fire', function(){
   event(new App\Events\NewUserSignup("james"));
   return "Event fired";
});

Route::get('/broadcasting/test', function(){
    return view('broadcasting_test');
});
```

Then I made my view (Resources\views\broadcasting_test) as followed:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<div class="container">
    <h1 id="addition">0</h1>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}" type="application/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.slim.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\NewUserSignup", function(message) {
        console.log('here');
        $('#addition').text(parseInt($('#addition').text()) + parseInt(message.data.addition));
    });
</script>
```

So I followed everything I was supposed to do. I started each and every step and even started the socket server using

```
node socket.js
```

Then I started the redis server but whenever I restart the firing page nothing happens at all! Nothing in my terminal changes, just nothing at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems to be right..I have tried out the same thing and it does work, Just to be sure did you run `php artisan config:clear` after setting your `BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis` in your .env file

Comment: @elporfirio Do u get any kind of error in your console?